# Request payload - Uploading a picture

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram, image-uploading, payload

I'm very familiar with Python's request library and have a good understanding about making requests. However, I have run into this particular payload for a certain POST request, and I am not really sure how it should be handled.

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9Bj6df0ErrnOvlr8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_id"

1532472043020
------WebKitFormBoundary9Bj6df0ErrnOvlr8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="photo.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9Bj6df0ErrnOvlr8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media_type"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary9Bj6df0ErrnOvlr8--
```

This payload is for uploading a picture to instagram.com with a simple web request.

**Question:**

*How does this payload translate to me selecting a picture on my desktop. Where would the file path come into play?*

---

Here is the code that is used to login into instagram.com. Please note that this is a method that is apart of a class I created. (Where the constructor takes ones username and password as parameters.

```
def logIn(self):
        self.loginPage = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/'
        self.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
        self.session.get(self.loginPage, proxies = {'http' : self.proxy, 'https' : self.proxy})
        self.session.headers = {'user-agent': self.userAgent}
        self.session.headers.update({'Referer': self.refererUrl, 'x-csrftoken': self.session.cookies['csrftoken']})
        loginData = {
            'username': self.username, 
            'password': self.password 
        }

        loginToPage = self.session.post(self.loginPage, data=loginData, allow_redirects=True, proxies = {'http' : self.proxy, 'https' : self.proxy})
        self.session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': self.session.cookies['csrftoken']})
        loginText = json.loads(loginToPage.text)
        print(loginToPage.text)
```

Here is also the request URL, that requires the payload above: https://www.instagram.com/create/upload/photo/

Comment: Where is the code that is doing the actual work?

Comment: Added more code to the OP.

Comment: You give a code snippet to show how you login but ask a question about how to upload a image? So what is the relationship?

Comment: The relationship is that you need to be logged in first in order to upload a picture. Then send a post request with the request url "https://www.instagram.com/create/upload/photo/" (which would be passed into the post method as an argument). The problem is I'm not sure how to deal with the payload it requires.